# Replace array of integers with array of objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

```
documents
id  | name | images
-------------------
int | text | int[]

images
id  | name | size
-----------------
int | text | int
```

What I would like is to get a document with all the details of its images.
For example I have this document:

```
id  | name   | images
---------------------
12  | 'test' | [7,5]
```

And these images:

```
id  | name   | size
---------------------
5   | 'img1' | 4659
7   | 'img8' | 6137
```

And I would like this result:

```
id  | name   | imagedetails
---------------------
12  | 'test' | [{name:'img1',size:4659},{name:'img8',size:6137}]
```

I tried to use "`WITH`", "`array_agg`" and "`json_build_object`", but I don't think I'm quite understanding how they work, although they should be the good functions.

If anybody could give me a hand, that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a rendering task, which is better suited and far easier for implementation in the application layer.

Comment: Actually I'm building a client to handle my pictures on my NAS :)

Comment: Avoid arrays of foreign keys. Use proper 3NF.

Comment: This is a good advice, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works but I'm not really sure it's optimal:

```
WITH list_images_brute AS (
    SELECT unnest(f.images) as images
    FROM documents d
    WHERE d.id = $1
)
, list_images AS (
    SELECT json_build_object('name',p.name,'size',p.size) as images, $1 as id
    FROM images p
    WHERE p.id IN(
        SELECT images
        FROM list_images_brute
    )
)
SELECT
    d.id, d.name, array_agg(lp.images) as imagedetails
    FROM documents d
    JOIN liste_images lp
        ON d.id = lp.id
    WHERE d.id = $1
    GROUP BY d.id, d.name
```